# CASE через ORM laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, orm

Как из данных

```
id | market | day | isOpen
1      ya      1       1
2      ya      2       0 
3      ya      3       1
...
```

Можно получить

```
id | market | monday | thuesday | wensday ...
   1     ya       1         0          1
```

Максимально используя ORM laravel

Пока что есть голый sql запрос

```
SELECT market,
SUM(CASE WHEN day = 1 and isOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
SUM(CASE WHEN day = 2 and isOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Thuesday,
SUM(CASE WHEN day = 3 and isOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday
FROM markets
GROUP BY market
```

Но хотелось бы чтобы он был универсальным и подходил под разные базы

Comment: Кстати, почитай хорошие практики Laravel https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8 особенно обрати внимание на именование столбцов в таблице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагается, что есть модель `Market`:

```
$res = Market::select('market')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(CASE WHEN day = 1 and isOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Monday')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(CASE WHEN day = 2 and isOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Thuesday')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(CASE WHEN day = 3 and isOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday')
    ->groupBy('market');
```